# How to search for substring using functional methods (without index/iteration) in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, substring

I'm learning Scala by going through books and implementing some standard algorithms in Scala for practice.

I'm trying to find a substring or do exact pattern matching program using brute force method first. I know that I can just use String.substring or iterate through the characters in each string (charAt). But I'm looking for any functional way to find substring (without using built in substring). To be clear, by functional I mean using immutables and avoiding manual iteration etc.

Comment: I don't see how substring is not functional. It does not have any side effects. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: @drexin It sounds to me like he wants to do himself just as an exercise in understanding how to think functionally.

Comment: I wonder what would be the point of asking for an answer then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a very broad question, so I'll provide some tips to help you get started on your exercise.  There are a myriad of ways to tackle this, and I'm sure the more experienced functional programmers will probably help even more. :)

First take your string, get the characters, and convert it into a list.  Taken from the Scala console:

```
scala> val str = "This string is just an example."
str: String = This string is just an example.

scala> val list = str.toCharArray.toList
res15: List[Char] = List(T, h, i, s,  , s, t, r, i, n, g,  , i, s,  , j, u, s, t,  , a, n,  , e, x, a, m, p, l, e, .)
```

An `Array` is mutable (see [Array Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array)), but a `List` is immutable (see [List Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List)).  Now you can start doing functional stuff on it. :)

Scala collections have a huge number of operations you can perform.  Some that I find most useful as an imperative programmer trying to unlearn bad habits are `map`, `reduce`, and `fold`.  For some tips on using them, check out my blog post [Map, reduce, and fold for the programmatically imperative](http://proseand.co.nz/2013/09/09/map-reduce-and-fold-for-the-programmatically-imperative/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The main issue for me is having the context. For example, I need to compare first characters of both the text and pattern, if they match, I need to proceed to the second character of both strings. By using foreach, I can iterate over each character but the context information like the current index of the character in this string and other is not available. I need some way to iterate over both string and pattern at the same time character by character.

Comment: I think this algorithm is inherently imperative and I want to know whether we can implement this using the built in operations like map, foreach instead of manual iteration.

Comment: It's not inherently imperative because functional programming is Turing complete. :)  If you need an index, call List's `zipWithIndex`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your suggestion to use zipWithIndex is what I'm looking for. I found a little tutorial at http://daily-scala.blogspot.in/2010/05/zipwithindex.html